# what is the best way to approach where next is depending on last step in django?

Tags: python, django, forms

My concern is i am implementing one application, where i have multiple steps and in each step i have multiple forms. in step one my form two is depending on form one.

Scenario 1:

And inside form one also few questions are there. depending on the answer of questions field should get changed in form.

```
for example
form 1
Q 1) Are you working?
ans) a) yes   b) No
```

if answer is yes it should display different fields and if no it should display diffident fields.

Scenario 2:

There is a address field in form 1 which i want to use in form 2. It should provide the option to select that address or enter new address.

Please provide me the best approach or available modules which i can use. If any specific name for this terminology please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django comes with a [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) that should be used for this kind of task. From the docs, the Form Wizard:

> ...splits forms across multiple Web pages. It maintains state in one of the backends so that the full server-side processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form.

Comment: is it possible to use form wizards in django form builder application? its a third party application.

Comment: @Gaurav , I doubt it...but I'm not familiar with that third-party application